# Chatheads pass through click event [Android]

Tags: android

I am currently experimenting with floating 'chat heads' in Android. For this, I add an ImageView to the screen using the WindowManager.

I was experimenting to pass through click events. In the future, I will use this to pass through double clicks to lower layers (apps upon which is drawn) and single clicks won't get through.

A lot of the solutions suggest to turn of the clickable parameter but this would mean I won't be able to detect the single clicks.

Another solution suggested:

```
View vp = (View) myFloatingView.getParent();
vp.performClick();
```

But this didn't work.

It is important to note that I use the WindowManager do draw my 'floating heads' and no activity.

Answer (score 0):

I did found this:

```
chatHead.setClickable(false);
chatHead.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

This disabled the clicking on the floating head but didn't pass click events through.